# How to update a label when a dropdown is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

My page has a label and a drop down list, which has time zones in it.  Is it possible to get the label text to change automatically to display the selected value from the drop down, every time the value in the times zones dropdown is changed?  How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a javascript function to update your label and call that from the onchange property of your dropdownlist.

Comment: its shows an error. of no selected Zone Found on local system

Comment: what's the javascript you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax or client side javascript to detech when the dropdown is selected.
If you do go for javascript make sure that this behaviour also works when javascript is turned off. I.E. submit the page and update the label on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

For reload the label you have to set the AutoPostBack in the DropDownList. 
So you can use on the Page_Load the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx).

[Here is an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx) found on MSDN :

```
    // Get Tokyo Standard Time zone
        TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
        DateTime tstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
        Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} zone: {1}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(tstTime) ?
                          tst.DaylightName : tst.StandardName, tstTime);
        Console.WriteLine("   UTC Time: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(tstTime, tst));
```

First of all you have to Find the TimeZone by ID. You can retrieve all the ID by using this method :

```
  System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneColl  = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

Then in a foreach cicle you can get the ID and bind in the dropdownlist values.

After all you have only to parametizer the example like this :

```
TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(*dropdownlistselectedvalue*);
DateTime tstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
Label1.Text = tstTime;
```

This is how you can Bind your dropdownlist :

```
  System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneColl = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        ddlTimeZones.DataSource = TimeZoneColl;
        ddlTimeZones.DataTextField = "StandardName";
        ddlTimeZones.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddlTimeZones.DataBind();
```

This is a working Example :

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneColl = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
            ddlTimeZones.DataSource = TimeZoneColl;
            ddlTimeZones.DataTextField = "StandardName";
            ddlTimeZones.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlTimeZones.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowTime();
        }


    }

    private void ShowTime()
    {
        DateTime thisTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(ddlTimeZones.SelectedValue);
        DateTime tstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
        lblShowTime.Text = tstTime.ToShortTimeString();

    }
}
```

Add only a dropdownlist on the page named "ddlTimeZones" and a Label named lblShowTime.

Hope it help...

Comment: sir, there Could be an error in 
TimeZoneInfo tst =TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);

Comment: What's the SelectedValue? it must be like this 'Pacific Standard Time'. And you can get all this values by call   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneColl  = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

Comment: TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(dropdownlist2.selectedvalue);
DateTime tstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
Label1.Text = tstTime;

Comment: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneColl = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
            DropDownList2.DataSource = TimeZoneColl;
            DropDownList2.DataBind();

Comment: this i add to bind the drop down list

Comment: I've added a working example.. tested on my machine. If you have any other question please contact me.